# Launching multiple functions with map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to do a parsing of an array in react js.
My array is (he can change but this is a example

```
[ "save", "save", "not", "save"]
```

Basically i'm trying to do a function who is launching another function every time he see "save".

Right now i have

```
 check(el) {
    if (el === "save")
    this.onSave()
    if (el === "not")
    this.onNot()
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var map_take = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tests"));
    {_.map(map_take, el => this.check(el))}
}
```

But my main problem is when i'm launching my program, he's doing one time and after, he's leaving. I Would like to know if it's possible to do a function who is launching another function X times and not only for the first element of my array.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you need, are you asking to call the check function every time localStorage gets updated?

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac sorry i'm not very clear, i just want to call my onSave function everytime i have "save" and my "onNot" function every time i have not in my map, and my problem is, right now, my onSave() function is called just one time

Comment: Do you really need this.onNot()? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me you have some unneeded complications in your code. Try something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() { // componentWillMount is deprecated
  const tests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tests"));

  tests.forEach((test) => {
    console.log(test); // this should fire 4 times with results like "save" or "not" just to check if everything is allright

    if (test === 'save') {
      this.onSave();
    } else if (test === 'not') {
      this.onNot()
    }
  })
}
```